# Is there a way in devise to check if current user signed in via session data?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, devise

I'm using devise in my rails app, but I'm also using angular within rails. In the angular context I don't have access to the typical rails methods like `session` or `current_user` or `signed_in?`

I'd like to check if the user is signed in, but I don't want to make a a server request to ask if there is a `current_user`. I'd like to just check the session or cookie store to determine this.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

Devise uses warden as a dependency and warden stores the information something like this inside the session if the user with id 1 is logged in

```
session["warden.user.user.key"] = [[1], "$2a$10$O3RAeV9c04lrlQ3T/I0PXe"]
```

and if not you will get it as nil.

Comment: But how do I access it from angular? There doesn't seem to be anything in window.sessionStorage. Is it a cookie?